# why i'm not able to fetch data using axios call?

Tags: reactjs

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState("general")

    const news = await axios.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=64968be4903a4a979fe05c58a3355a73
            &category=${category}`);
```

> **As I am fetching API but its not fetching as is shows an empty array can anyone tell me where I am I going wrong **
> [image: Result of that url provided]

Comment: please attach more details response screenshot

Comment: what do you wanna know please lemme know i'll post that

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use the response of an async function directly in your React functional component. You have to use a state which holds your `news`. If you call `setNews` React automatically rerenders your component with the new news data.

```
export function News() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("general");
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

  // fetch news everytime the category changes
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchNews() {
      try {
        const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=64968be4903a4a979fe05c58a3355a73&category=${category}`;
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        console.log(response);
        setNews(response.data.articles);
      } catch (errorWhileFetchingNews) {
        console.log("error while fetching news", errorWhileFetchingNews);
      }
    }

    fetchNews();
  }, [category]);

  // render the news
  return (
    <div>
      {
        news.map((article, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{article.title}</div>;
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

**CAUTION**: The CORS issues seem to appear only in my codesandbox example. If the example above runs on localhost:3000 in a normal React app (create-react-app) it works like it should. So you might ignore the following description.

Unfortunately the server *newsapi.org* doesn't send CORS headers. So you are not allowed to call this service directly via AJAX requests (`axios`, `fetch`, ...). You either find a way to enable CORS on this site (because you have an API key you may be able to administrate something?) or you find an other service that supports CORS or you have to send your request through a proxy. The proxy/backend then have to run on the same domain (host + port) like your frontend or the proxy must handle all the CORS header stuff. There are also questions on stackoverflow that have the same issue with newsapi.org but I am afraid that there is no easy solution/workaround for this.

I have setup a working example with *jsonplaceholder.typicode.com* (supports CORS) instead of *newsapi.org*.

See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-wildflower-su5vd?file=/src/News.js

Just in case the example is not reachable anymore, here is the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export function News(props) {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("general");
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

  // fetch news everytime the category changes
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchNews() {
      try {
        const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        console.log(response);
        setNews(response.data);
      } catch (errorWhileFetchingNews) {
        console.log("error while fetching news", errorWhileFetchingNews);
      }
    }

    fetchNews();
  }, [category]);

  // render the news
  return (
    <div>
      {
        news.map((article) => {
          return <div key={article.id}>{article.name}</div>;
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: but the dependency should be provided as news and category because as category changes news should also change?

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer. Every time the `category` changes the `useEffect` runs and fetches the news for the current category.

Comment: its showing some sort of error, it shows update dependencies as fetchNews,category why so?

Comment: also this url doesn't fetch any  kind of data, but if manually enter category as general it shows everthing whats happening i'm not getting it please help

Comment: I had a closer look on this issue and extended my answer. See the block starting with "EDIT".

Comment: Hmm strange... when I run my first example on localhost:3000 it works and outputs the titles of the articles.

Comment: but there is one thing i tried, when we directly write a category instead of getting it, the url works fine. I'm confused my i ran the same code on my friend's lochalhost ,it worked fine why i'm getting the error

Comment: Hard to tell because it also works on my localhost. I think your best chance is to open the DevTools of your browser (press F12 in Chrome/FireFox) and view the request/response in the network tab. Then you can compare your version with the working version of your friend and maybe find some differences. Also have a look into the console output. Maybe there are some errors listed.

Comment: Make sure that there are no line breaks in the url string like in your question.

Comment: i tried with another API, it worked i don't know

Comment: Great to hear that it works. Now you are able to compare the request of axios with the request of your new API in the network tab of the DevTools and find the difference (maybe some request headers or so). Or you stick with your new API if you don't have to use axios.